# restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.POST,entity1,Response.class)) is returned null object instead of responseEntity stubbed data when mockito applied

Tags: java, spring, rest, mockito

This is my call to be mocked:

```
ResponseEntity<Response> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Response.class);
```

mocking like below :

```
@Test
    public void getSpecalityInventoryItemsCallPositiveTest(){

        RestTemplateBuilder restTemplateBuilder = Mockito.mock(RestTemplateBuilder.class);
    RestTemplate restTemplate = Mockito.mock(RestTemplate.class);

    GetSpecalityInventoryItemsCaller getSpecalityInventoryItemsCaller = new GetSpecalityInventoryItemsCaller(restTemplateBuilder,id,pw);

    Response inventoryItemsRespone = new Response();
    inventoryItemsRespone.setStatusCode("0000");
    BDDMockito.given(restTemplateBuilder.messageConverters(BDDMockito.any(ArrayList.class))).willReturn(restTemplateBuilder);
    BDDMockito.given(restTemplateBuilder.additionalInterceptors(BDDMockito.any(ArrayList.class))).willReturn(restTemplateBuilder);
    BDDMockito.given(restTemplateBuilder.build()).willReturn(restTemplate);

    ResponseEntity<Response> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<Response>(inventoryItemsRespone, HttpStatus.OK);

    BDDMockito.given(restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.POST,HttpEntity.EMPTY,Response.class)).willReturn(responseEntity);

    Response response = getSpecalityInventoryItemsCaller.getSpecalityInventoryItemsCaller(rxNumber);

    Assertions.assertThat(response.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo("0000");
}
```

but `getSpecalityInventoryItemsCaller.getSpecalityInventoryItemsCaller(rxNumber)` is executed , inside `restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, entity, Response.class);` call is returning null response

i need my own response Response

```
inventoryItemsRespone = new Response();
        inventoryItemsRespone.setStatusCode("0000");
```

Not getting my own response , please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the stubbing you are doing is matching on exact arguments. The problem is that the actual method may call may include arguments which have the same value as your stubbing but are not the same actual objects.

You should try using matchers for the restTemplate stubbing too:

```
BDDMockito.given(restTemplate.exchange(any(),any(),any(),any())).willReturn(responseEntity);
```

Although you might want to make it more precise than the any() matchers I have used here as an example, but it's worth testing to see if this works.

Comment: Thanks for reply : but i used BDDMockito.given(restTemplate.exchange(url,HttpMethod.POST, BDDMockito.any(HttpEntity.class), Response.class)).willReturn(responseEntity); error like below: 4 matchers expected, 1 recorded:

Comment: please share your example.

Comment: That wont work because you cant mix matchers with exact arguments. They need to all be matchers if you use matchers.

Comment: BDDMockito.given(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(),Mockito.any(), BDDMockito.any(),Response.class)).willReturn(responseEntity); but for last parameter Response.class , not able to pass mockito.any() pls suggest?

Comment: It should work.. can try Mockito.any(Class.class) or Mockito.eq(Response.class) instead

Comment: BDDMockito.given(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), BDDMockito.any(),BDDMockito.<Class<Response>>any())).willReturn(responseEntity); it is working when BDDMockito.<Class<Response>>any() changed !! Thanks a lot !!!!!!!! :)

Comment: BDDMockito.given(restTemplate.exchange(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(), BDDMockito.any(), BDDMockito.<Class<Response>>any())).willReturn(responseE‌​ntity); working Great Thanks !!!!!

Comment: No problem, accept my answer / give me an up vote if you found it useful!